# Exception occurred while getting Hibernate sequence nextVal (Oracle)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and hibernate in my application and  below is the  configuration in Model class.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ", sequenceName="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ")
@Column(name="INQ_ID")
private Integer inquiryId;
```

Previously It was xml configuration for database mapping as below.

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.company.domain.model.AnalystInquiryForm" table="INQUIRY_QUEUE" schema="SCHEMA1">
        <id name="inquiryId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="INQ_ID"/>
           <generator class="sequence">
             <param name="sequence">SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ</param>
           </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="transactionDate" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
          <column name="INQ_ADD_DT" />
        </property>
    </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Getting the below error

```
16:08:36.873 [http-nio-8551-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select schema1.inquiry_queue_seq.nextval from dual
16:08:37.419 [http-nio-8551-exec-2] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
16:08:37.431 [http-nio-8551-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


16:36:23.977 [http-nio-8551-exec-2] ERROR com.company.user.controller.UserController - Error in processAnalystInquiry : could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

And my spring boot configuration is as below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version> 
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc15</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And  middle layer is

```
@Autowired
private AnalystInquiryFormRepository analystInquiryFormRepository;
public void addToInquiryQueue(AnalystInquiryForm form) {
     analystInquiryFormRepository.save(form);
}
```

My repository is..

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.company.user.model.AnalystInquiryForm;
public interface AnalystInquiryFormRepository extends 
CrudRepository<AnalystInquiryForm, Integer>{

}
```

Comment: are you sure that your schema1.inquiry_queue_seq exists in your DB?

Comment: this is not an exitsting table . It is autogenerated by hibernate. This is @SequenceGenerator name

Comment: yes but here sequenceName="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ" you specify the name of the DB sequence, this sequence must exist in DB

Comment: @Michal how to check that if DB sequence is exist in DB

Comment: if you you connect to DB (via some sql client) and call what hibernate does "select schema1.inquiry_queue_seq.nextval from dual". But I would expect that it is missing. you need to create it in DB. e.g. CREATE SEQUENCE INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ;

Comment: @Michal It was working before with same sequence. When it was xml configuration, check above I have updated my question.

Comment: Debug, put a breakpoint at  analystInquiryFormRepository.save(form); and then check table from sql client externally

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ")`

That means DB should have a table named: SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ.

If the table already exists, make sure that the user with which you are accessing this table, has all the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Right it was access issue. Worked after executing following query.
GRANT   SELECT   ON   SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ TO   APUSER;

Answer (score 0):

Either table or View does not exist or problem in your query, Check once whether query is accurate or not.

Comment: This is auto generated query from hibernate. This is @SequenceGenerator(name="SCHEMA1.INQUIRY_QUEUE_SEQ")